# Matlab Simulink interface problem(Simpower Systems vs Simscape)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, matlab, simulink

For my rechargeble  battery model in Simulink,i need a switch that needs to control the voltages across 2 points and according to a certain level it changes its state. To implement this in Simulink i use Voltage-Controlled Switch which belongs to a different library than by cells whose voltages are 12 Volts each. After connecting "Voltage-Current Interface(Ground)" to my circuit  to connect these two objects of two different libraries i get an error stating the following. How can i fix this problem. Do you have any suggestions that i can do to accomplish my task. You can find the design and the error message below.[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you are mixing SimPowerSystems & SimScape?

With the introduction of SimScape "SimPowerSystems", the legacy method of dealing with electrical simulations has become redundant EXCEPT for some legacy blocks and specialised technologies.

The legacy SimPowerSystems does have a more specialised battery model so I can understand why you would want to use that *IF* it provides features the simscape battery does not (or that you cannot reproduce...)

[image]

you can run with both as long as you provide the needed pre-requisites.
I don't see a SimScape reference block nor a solver block. Do they exist.

---

The actual problem here is an algebraic loop.

the subsystem highlighted within the 1st post. What EXACTLY is in there?  I suspect there is some form of **SimPowerSystem** voltage sensor to bring a signal into the **simulink** domain, a **Simulink-PS** converter block to take it into the **SimScape** domain. This is where it needs to be solved.

Add a memory block in the simulink domain should break the loop and provided the needed initial condition (if you are running continuous consider adding a TF with a small timeconstant todo the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

> Try to avoid using simpowersystem and simscap components in the same simulation file.

To solve the simulation error, you can simply use "ideal switch" block from Simpowersystem>Power electronics library.

On the other hand you can use a DC-DC converter (boost or buck ... etc) with a dc voltage source to charge the battery. I do not see any logic in connecting a current source directly to the battery terminals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That helps a lot. I try to use the ideal switch but as far as i understand the switch opearates with respect to "0" but in my application it should be "20" Volts.

Comment: This switch works as per the gate (g) signal (for 0 it is opened,  1 it is closed) regardless the circuit voltage.


You have other alternatives like (breaker>elements>simpowersystems) in case if you want to use it only for switching on/off for longer period. Ideal swirtch, however, can be used instead of a power electronic switch like a transistor or thyristor (with neglecting all the losses and the delay of these switches).